# backupskip with { curly braces

Tags: vimrc, set

There's a project where I don't want Vim to write in a temp buffer and rename, because my files are watched by another program for writes (and not renamings).

I've tried this in my `.vimrc`:

```
set backupskip+=*/static/{templates/*.html,js/*.ts}
```

The goal is to ignore both the `templates/` and the `js/` directory.

But when I save, I'm getting: `E220: Missing }.`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the comma is interpreted by `set+=` command.

So for this to work, one should escape it:

`set backupskip+=*/web/static/{js/*.ts\\,templates/*.html}`